# How to write a program in java that will take 5 integers and output the minimum and the maximum integer?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that will ask for 5 integer values which I already have complete. However, now I need to know how to get my program to output the minimum and maximum values of the 5. I know that there is a possibility to use if statements but that would be 120 different if statements. I was wondering if there was an easier way to find the maximum and minimum.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  Please show your code.  look at arrays and loops.

Answer (score 0):

Put the numbers in an array, sort the array, then take the first and last element.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need 120 different if statements?
You've already gotten answers about calling math functions to get the job done, I've used a simple sorting method to get the job done.

The solution to your problem is divided into the following:
1) Reading the user input
2) Sorting that
3) Find the max min from the sorted bunch

Code:

```
//Import relevant packages

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class MinMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] myArray = new int[5];  //Array to hold user input of 5 integers
        int[] resultArray;  //reference var to hold the resultArray object

        //Buffered reader is wrapped around the input stream reader to read user input
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //Loop to get user input, 5 times
        for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            try{
                myArray[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());  //String to integer the user     input
                }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
        //Calling the function sortme() to do the sorting
        resultArray = sortme(myArray);

        //After bubble sort has sorted the input array, the min is the first and max is the last,     values of the array
        System.out.println("The min is: " + resultArray[0] + ", and the max is: "+myArray[4]);      
    }

    //Bubble sort
    static int[] sortme(int[] array){
        int temp;

        for (int i=(array.length-1);i>=0;i--){

            for (int j=1;j<=i;j++){
                if (array[j-1] > array[j]){
                    temp = array[j-1];
                    array[j-1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Input:

```
1 4 6 3 9
```

Output:

```
The min is: 1, and the max is: 9
```

**EDIT**
Mr. Yetti, pointed out the inefficiency of the sorting method, as it is not needed in the first place. Here is the iterating method:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class MinMax_nosort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] myArray = new int[5];  //Array to hold user input of 5 integers

            //Buffered reader is wrapped around the input stream reader to read user input
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            //Loop to get user input, 5 times
            for (int i=1;i<=5;i++){
                System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
                try{
                    myArray[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());  //String to integer the user input
                    }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            minmax(myArray);            
        }

    static void minmax(int[] array){
        int max, min;
        max = min = array[0];
        for (int i=1;i<array.length;i++){
            if (array[i] > max)
                max = array[i];
            else if(array[i] < min)
                min = array[i];
        }
        System.out.println("The min is:" + min + " and the max, is: " + max);
    }
```

Input:

```
1 4 6 3 9
```

Output:

```
The min is:1 and the max, is: 9
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] test = {1, 4, 2, 10, 5};
Arrays.sort(test);
System.out.println("Smallest:" + test[0] + "  Largest:" + test[4]);
```

Store in array then sort the array.

Comment: Why did you downvote the correct answer atleast say why.

Comment: because sorting is a complete overhead when looking for min/max elements.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case he asked for a solution and he got one where is your solution.  This is a simple way to do it for a beginner. Easy for him to understand.

Comment: it's funny that you don't care whether or how bad your solution is, instead trying to take revenge on me by downvoting my answer. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Yetti: what kind of performance gain are you expecting with your approach?

Comment: O(n) versus O(nlogn) when sorting.

Comment: Then I would stick with the 120 if-statements. Why even bother learning the correct way of solving the min/max task, when there is a solution already, right?

Comment: @Mr.Yetti: well no, because there's a difference between writing 120 if-statements and a clear 3-liner like the one above.

Comment: Ok, then compare it to the one-liner I posted in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Put the numbers into an array or a collection, initialise a variable that will store your min or max (with an `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, respectively), then iterate the array/collection, each time comparing current element with the variable's value and updating the variable when necessary.

---

EDIT: one-liner for this solution as requested in the comments.

```
int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(number1, number2, number3, number4, number5));
```

Same for `min`.